# Post string to API

Tags: javascript, next.js, fetch-api

I am trying to send the contract address to my API but the API endpoint just says undefined when I try to pass it. When I paste the `contractAddres` directly in the API code it works put when I want to fetch the address from outside the API it dosen't work. I don't get why since the new app structure of nextjs aim also a little bit confused with the route system but this seems to be right because it works when I call the address in the same file.

This is my frontend with fetch:

```js
"use client"
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function NFTGallery() {
    const [nfts, setNfts] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    async function fetchNFTs() {
        console.log("Starting to fetch NFTs..."); // Log start of fetching
        setIsLoading(true); // Start loading

        try {
            const contractAdd = { address: "0xBC4CA0EdA7647A8aB7C2061c2E118A18a936f13D" }; // Set contract address
            console.log("Fetching NFTs for contract:", contractAdd); // Log API request
            const response = await fetch('/api/getNftForContract', { // Note the API endpoint change
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(contractAdd),
            });

            const data = await response.json();
            console.log("Response data:", data); // Log response data

            if (data.nfts) {
                console.log(`Found ${data.nfts.length} NFTs`); // Log number of NFTs found
                setNfts(data.nfts);
            } else {
                console.log("No NFTs found in response"); // Log when no NFTs found
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching NFTs:", error); // Log errors
        }

        setIsLoading(false); // Stop loading
        console.log("Finished fetching NFTs"); // Log end of fetching
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchNFTs();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className='transparent relative isolate px-6 lg:px-8 '>
            {isLoading ? (
                <div className="flex justify-center items-center h-40">Loading...</div>
            ) : (
                <div className='grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 xl:grid-cols-6 gap-4 p-4 '>
                    {nfts.map((nft, index) => (
                        <div key={index} className="p-4">
                            <div className="p-6 rounded-lg shadow-xl">
                                <img src={nft.media} alt={nft.title || 'NFT Image'} className="h-40 rounded w-full object-cover object-center mb-6" />
                                <h2 className="text-lg text-gray-900 font-medium title-font mb-4">{nft.collectionName}</h2>
                                <a href="#" className="text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900">Learn More →</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

and this is my API:

```js
import { Network, Alchemy } from "alchemy-sdk";

export async function POST(req) {
  const { address, pageKey, pageSize, chain } = JSON.parse(req.body);
  const settings = {
    apiKey: "", // Replace with your actual API key
    network: Network.ETH_MAINNET,
  };

  const alchemy = new Alchemy(settings);

  try {
    // Format checking and console logging
    if (!req.body) {
      return new Response(JSON.stringify({ message: "No request body" }), {
        status: 400,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      });
    }
   

    const nftsResponse = await alchemy.nft.getNftsForContract(address);
    console.log("NFTs response from Alchemy:", nftsResponse);

    // Check if nftsResponse is empty or undefined
    if (!nftsResponse.nfts || nftsResponse.nfts.length === 0) {
      console.log("No NFTs found for the given contract address.");
      return new Response(JSON.stringify({ nfts: null }), {
        status: 200,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      });
    }

    // Formatting the NFT data
    const formattedNfts = nftsResponse.nfts.map((nft) => {
      const { contract, title, tokenType, tokenId, description, media } = nft;
      return {
        contract: contract.address,
        symbol: contract.symbol,
        media: media[0]?.gateway
          ? media[0]?.gateway
          : "https://via.placeholder.com/500",
        collectionName: contract.openSea?.collectionName,
        verified: contract.openSea?.safelistRequestStatus,
        tokenType,
        tokenId,
        title,
        description,
        format: media[0]?.format ? media[0]?.format : "png",
      };
    });

    console.log("Formatted NFTs:", formattedNfts);

    const filteredNfts = formattedNfts.filter(
      (nft) => nft.media
    );

    console.log("Filtered NFTs:", filteredNfts);

    return new Response(JSON.stringify({
      nfts: filteredNfts.length ? filteredNfts : null
    }), {
      status: 200,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ message: error.message }), {
      status: 500,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    });
  }
}
```